# OpenCV ERROR: Formats of input arguments do not match

Tags: opencv

I can't understand why my program doesn't run on my PC while on the school computer it works fine! Perhaps it's a problem on the configuration. I work with Ubuntu 9.10 and the last version of opencv 2.2

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double a[9]={1,0,-1,2,0,-2,1,0,-1};
    double b[9]={1,2,1,0,0,0,-1,-2,-1};

    IplImage* img=cvLoadImage(argv[1], 0);
    if(!img){
        printf("could not load image file: %s\n",argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }   

    IplImage* dst=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_64F,1);
    IplImage* dst1=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_64F,1);
    IplImage* dst2=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_64F,1);
    IplImage* dst_f=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    CvMat k1 = cvMat(3,3,CV_64FC1,a);
    CvMat k2 = cvMat(3,3,CV_64FC1,b);
    cvFilter2D( img ,dst1, &k1,cvPoint(-1,-1));
    cvFilter2D( img ,dst2, &k2,cvPoint(-1,-1));
    cvPow(dst1, dst1, 2.0);
    cvPow(dst2, dst2, 2.0);
    cvAdd(dst1, dst2, dst, NULL);
    cvPow(dst, dst, 0.5);
    cvConvertImage(dst,dst_f,CV_CVTIMG_FLIP);
    cvThreshold(dst_f,dst_f,127,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 100, 100);
    cvShowImage("mainWin",img);
    cvNamedWindow("Sobel", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Sobel",dst_f);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseImage(&dst_f);
    return 0;
}
```

this is what the terminal returns when running

> OpenCV ERROR: Formats of input
>   arguments do not match ()     in function
>   cvFilter2D, cvfilter.cpp(2617)
>   Terminating the application...    called
>   from cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...    called from
>   cvUnregisterType,
>   cxpersistence.cpp(4933) Terminating
>   the application...

Please help me to understand the problem.

Comment: Looks OK to me - the only thing I can suggest is try using 32 bit floats instead of 64 bit, i.e. change your doubles to floats, IPL_DEPTH_64F to IPL_DEPTH_32F and CV_64FC1 to CV_32FC1, etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul :)
I changed the depth as you've suggested and I kept IPL_DEPTH_8U for the final image ! but it didn't solve my problem I  get the same message .

Answer (score 0):

Your error is tjat you need to work with CvMat variables to store matrix to store your filter and to apply it into an image with cvFilter 2D.

I give you 2 sample codes to understand this procedures.

Create and initialize a matrix.

```
double a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4
              5, 6, 7, 8,
              9, 10, 11, 12 };

double b[] = { 1, 5, 9,
              2, 6, 10,
              3, 7, 11,
              4, 8, 12 };
double c[9];
CvMat Ma, Mb, Mc ;

cvInitMatHeader( &Ma, 3, 4, CV_64FC1, a );
cvInitMatHeader( &Mb, 4, 3, CV_64FC1, b );
cvInitMatHeader( &Mc, 3, 3, CV_64FC1, c );

cvMatMulAdd( &Ma, &Mb, 0, &Mc );
// c array now contains product of a(3x4) and b(4x3) matrices
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of High Pass Filtering with another option to matrix initialization

```
int main()
```

{
    CvMat* kernel=0;
    IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("chica.jpg");
    IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),32,3);

```
kernel = cvCreateMat(3, 3,CV_32FC1);
cvSet2D( kernel, 0, 0, cvRealScalar(0));
cvSet2D( kernel, 0, 1, cvRealScalar(-1));
cvSet2D( kernel, 0, 2, cvRealScalar(0));
cvSet2D( kernel, 1, 0, cvRealScalar(-1));
cvSet2D( kernel, 1, 1, cvRealScalar(5));
cvSet2D( kernel, 1, 2, cvRealScalar(-1));
cvSet2D( kernel, 2, 0, cvRealScalar(0));
cvSet2D( kernel, 2, 1, cvRealScalar(-1));
cvSet2D( kernel, 2, 2, cvRealScalar(0));

// Matriz utilizada para el filtrado paso alto
// 0 -1 0
// -1 5 -1
// 0 -1 0

cvFilter2D(src, dst, kernel, cvPoint(-1,-1));

cvNamedWindow("Image Original",1);
cvShowImage("Image Original",src);

cvNamedWindow("Image Filtrada",1);
cvShowImage("Image Filtrada",src);

cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseImage(&src);
cvReleaseImage(&dst);

cvDestroyWindow("Image Original");
cvDestroyWindow("Image Filtrada");
// release the image


return 0;
```

}